# install tensorflow 2.6.0 on google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm using trying to run this script on google colab :

```
   !pip3 install tensorflow==2.6.0
```

I get this error :

```
   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.6.0 (from versions: 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1)

   ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.6.0
```

I'm a biginner to google colab, any idea on how to run the script and configure the TPU

I tried to describe my issue and give code example and everything worked fine

Comment: Currently, some version of TensorFlow is not working, you can try with another version, like: `!pip3 install tensorflow==2.8.0`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```